# combining input from form into 1 rows

Tags: php

i want to combine `fname` and `lname` into a one input

```
$fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
$lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
```

and i want input this result into my sql table

```
 function random_username( $length = 4 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $usercode;
}
```

how about that combining code?

NOTE: *Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's unclear what you want to ask. If you want to combine fname and lname, then simply concatenate them. `fname . " " . $lname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you want to concate `firstname` and `lastname` then simply use `concatnation`

```
$fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
$lname = trim($_POST['lname']);

$userfullname = $fname." ".$lname; // this will give use your fullname
```

Comment: and how to shuffle that full name? and give shuffle code?
shuffle code :
`function random_username( $length = 4 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $usercode;
}`

Comment: @arigohafnan Sorry i dont get what is meant by shuffle that full name. Please update your question for that and also why you retuen $usercode in function you should return $password.